# Correct way to refractor if-statements

Tags: java, android, if-statement, refactoring

I wonder if this is a good way to refactor multiple if statements? What I have heard is that if-statements are "bad" practice and i would like to take my programing to the next level by refactor some of my code.

Original code:

```
public int Colors(String col, int row){
    int ret = 0;
    if(col.equals("R")){
        ret = Color.parseColor("#EF5350");
    }else if(col.equals("B")) {
        ret = Color.parseColor("#7986CB");
    }else if(col.equals("V")){
        ret = Color.WHITE;
    }else if(col.equals("G")){
     ret = Color.parseColor("#FFE082");
    }else if(Math.floorMod(row,2) == 0){
        ret = Color.parseColor("#e0e0e0");
    }else{
         ret = Color.parseColor("#eeeeee");
    }
```

return ret;
    }

New code:

```
public int Colors(String col, int row){

    Map<String,Integer> ColorMap1 = new HashMap<>();

    ColorMap1.put("R", Color.parseColor("#EF5350"));
    ColorMap1.put("B",Color.parseColor("#7986CB"));
    ColorMap1.put("V",Color.parseColor("#FFE082"));
    ColorMap1.put("G",Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

    Integer current = ColorMap1.get(col);

    Map<Integer,Integer> ColorMap2 = new HashMap<>();

    ColorMap2.put(0,Color.parseColor("#e0e0e0"));
    ColorMap2.put(1,Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"));

    Integer current2 = ColorMap2.get(Math.floorMod(row,2));

    return  current != null ? current  : current2 ;
```

}

Comment: `if` is good enough. If you are going Map way, you should create static map to avoid cost of object creation

Comment: Better candidate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I personally think the first one is fine. Also, by using the Maps you are creating a lot of temporary objects which aren't good for performance.

Comment: An alternative to the if/else ladder is a switch. That could be marginally faster, since the lookup is then constant time, rather than linear in the number of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` in general is not bad practice. It's just that when you find yourself using multiple chained `if`-`else if` blocks in a row, that's usually code smell that indicates you could be doing what you are doing more efficiently.

In this case, using a static `Map` is a good way to refactor your most of your code to be more efficient than the `if` equivalent. The problem is that, because one of the conditions doesn't match the rest and it isn't a constant value. So you can partially refactor your code like this:

```
static HashMap<String, Color> colorMap;

static {
    colorMap = new HashMap<>();
    colorMap.put("R",Color.parseColor("#EF5350"));
    colorMap.put("B",Color.parseColor("#7986CB"));
    colorMap.put("V",Color.parseColor("#FFE082"));
    colorMap.put("G",Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
}

// ...

public int Colors(String col, int row) {
    if (colorMap.containsKey(col)) {
      return colorMap.get(col);
    }

    if (Math.floorMod(row, 2) == 0) {
      return Color.parseColor("#e0e0e0");
    }

    return Color.parseColor("#eeeeee");
}
```

Alternatively, you can accomplish a similar thing with a `switch` block:

```
public int Colors(String col, int row) {
    switch (col) {
        case "R": return Color.parseColor("#EF5350");
        case "B": return Color.parseColor("#7986CB");
        case "V": return Color.parseColor("#FFE082");
        case "G": return Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF");
    }

    if (Math.floorMod(row, 2) == 0) {
      return Color.parseColor("#e0e0e0");
    }

    return Color.parseColor("#eeeeee");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If-statements aren't inherently bad. They can be a bit clunky for large comparison blocks, but in Java, there's no universal alternative. (You could use `when` in Kotlin.)

Since you've got a big block there, and you're comparing Strings, you can always use a switch statement, for most of it:

```
public int colors(String col, int row) //method names in Java should usually use camelCase, not TitleCase
    switch(col) {
        case "R":
            return Color.parseColor("#EF5350");
        case "B":
            return Color.parseColor("#7986CB");
        case "V":
            return Color.WHITE;
        case "G":
            return Color.parseColor("#FFE082");
        default: //comparable to an "else" statement
            if (Math.floorMod(row, 2) == 0) return Color.parseColor("#e0e0e0");
            else return Color.parseColor("#eeeeee");
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for `break` in the default case; no need for `int ret = 0;` either.

Comment: @AndyTurner good catch on the second part, but I'm just being careful with the `default` case, since it isn't always at the bottom.

Comment: Also, you can dispense with the `break`s if you just return directly from the cases.

Comment: @AndyTurner done. I've been using Kotlin lately, so I've gotten used to just doing `return when() {...`

Answer (score 0):

It's arguable that `if-statements` or `switch-statements` are always bad. Sometimes they lead to much more concise code. But if number of cases grows really high, then it becomes cleaner to use `Map`.

You can use map registry for colors as follows:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private static int DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#eeeeee");
    private static Map<ColorKey, Integer> COLORS = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        COLORS.put(ColorKey.of("R", null), Color.parseColor("#EF5350"));
        COLORS.put(ColorKey.of("B", null), Color.parseColor("#7986CB"));
        COLORS.put(ColorKey.of("V", null), Color.WHITE);
        COLORS.put(ColorKey.of("G", null), Color.parseColor("#FFE082"));
        COLORS.put(ColorKey.of(null, 0), Color.parseColor("#e0e0e0"));
    }

    public Integer colors(String col, int row) {
        return COLORS.getOrDefault(ColorKey.of(col, row), DEFAULT_COLOR);
    }

    private static final class ColorKey {
       private final String col;
       private final Integer row;
       private ColorKey(String col, Integer row) {
           this.col = col; this.row = row;
       }
       private static ColorKey of(String col, Integer row) {
           return new ColorKey(key(col), key(row));
       }
       private static String key(String col) {
           Set<String> columns = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("R", "B", "V", "G"));
           return columns.contains(col) ? col : null;
       }
       private static Integer key(Integer row) {
           return row != null && Math.floorMod(row,2) == 0 ? Integer.valueOf(0) : null;
       }
       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object obj) {
           if (obj == null) return false;
           if (obj == this)  return true;
           if (!(obj instanceof ColorKey)) return false;
           ColorKey that = (ColorKey) obj;
           return Objects.equals(this.col, that.col) && Objects.equals(this.row, that.row);
       }
       @Override
       public int hashCode() {
           int result = 17;
           result = 31 * result + Objects.hash(col);
           result = 31 * result + Objects.hash(row);
           return result;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`If` statement is bad practice if you used it excessively and in different places. 
The best way to refactor it is to use a design pattern 
There are many patterns can be used instead of `if` statement, like `strategy`, `state` or `command` pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can use enum to add different colors:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String colorName = "R";
        int row = 23;
        System.out.println("Color code: " + ColorSchema.getColor(colorName, row).getCode());
    }
}


enum ColorSchema {

  R("#EF5350"), 
  B("#7986CB"), 
  V("#FFE082"),
  G("#FFFFFF"),

  ROW0("#e0e0e0"),
  ROW1("#eeeeee");

  private String color;

  ColorSchema(String color) {this.color = color;}
  public int getCode(){ return Color.parseColor(color);}

  public static ColorSchema getColor(String name, int row) {
    for (ColorSchema c : ColorSchema.values()) {
      if (c.color.equals(name)) {
        return c;
      }
    }
    return ColorSchema.valueOf("ROW" + Math.floorMod(row, 2));
  }

}
```